# Can or How to use Python asyncio on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio

Is it possible to use Python's `asyncio` on Google Cloud Functions?

```
async def handle_someting():
    # do something
    some = await aiofunc()

# Do I need the code below?
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(handle_someting())
loop.close()
```

Comment: Without knowing more about which gcloud functionality you want to invoke, it's hard to say. You won't be able to just `await blob.download('file')` for instance, because blob.download is not an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, you just need to run the async functions from your main deployed function (here, you would deploy the `test` function):

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    return 'Asynchronicity!'

async def bar():
    return await foo()

def test(request):
    return asyncio.run(bar())
```

Comment: @Robino The last function here (`test`) is a Google Cloud Function. This example demonstrates how to use asyncio with a Cloud Function, just like the OP asked...

Comment: @Robino I'm not sure you understand what a Google Cloud Function is. See https://cloud.google.com/functions

Comment: I'm talking nonsense. Sorry for wasting your time. I shall delete my comments.

Comment: Hi @DustinIngram I am facing timeout issue when running the asyncio as you suggested. Can you please look at this questuion? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095735/asyncio-not-working-on-google-cloud-functions
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Tertiary question, what happens / what are the downsides of not using async/await when creating python function in Google Cloud Functions? Ie. why do one vs the other?

Comment: Not a good solution! It works but it wont run on event-loop as in async-native clouds like Azure and Yandex!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to run async code in Google Cloud Functions.

To achieve that, you need to manually create new event loop and then call it from entry-point method that receives the request. Code example:

```
import asyncio

eventLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(eventLoop)

async def processJson(rawRequest: dict) -> None:
    """Processes received request JSON."""
    print(rawRequest)
    <some logic here>


async def wrapper(request):
    """Async wrapper."""

    if request.method != "POST":
        return "not POST"

    rawRequest: dict = request.get_json(silent=True)

    await processJson(rawRequest)

    return "OK"

def entryPoint(request) -> str:
    """Entry-point that is triggered by cloud function URL."""

    return eventLoop.run_until_complete(wrapper(request))
```

Deploying this code and doing GET request to your google cloud function will return you "not POST".
Sending it as POST request will trigger any logics you've wrote inside `processJson()` and return "OK".