# Python/Cloud Functions Asynchronous POST Requests

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function (python) that iterates through a dataset and triggers other Google Cloud Functions (within the iteration) if certain criteria are met.

Is there a way to send HTTP POST requests to a cloud function without waiting for a response? Waiting for a response is slowing my iterator function down.

I've been exploring the `timeout` parameter in the `requests` module but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
requests.post(function_trigger,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload), timeout=0.5)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do asynchronous requests using Python libraries such as [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) which you'll find a small example on how to use in Cloud Functions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52767429/8456296) Stackoverflow answer.

You can also achieve asynchronous functionality integrating your function with [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#triggering_the_function) or [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub).