# asyncio not working on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, telegram-api, pyrogram

I have this function which works fine locally on my machine with python 3.8, but it throws runtime error on Google Cloud Functions.

```
def telegram_test(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    from pyrogram import Client
    
    session_string = "...............38Q8uTHG5gHwyWD8nW6h................."
    # the rest of the authantication
    api_id = 32494131641215
    api_hash = "ioadsfsjnjksfgnfriuthg#qw]/zwq  ]w/\lc ec,"

    # one of bbc channels on telegram you want to access
    channel_name = 'pyrogram'

    # if you only want to get messages older than 7 days in unix style
    seven_days = int((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)).timestamp())
    # call telegram with parameters such as limit and date
    # save the result to dataframe

    with Client(session_string,api_id,api_hash, takeout=True,workers=2) as app:
        hist_iter = app.iter_history(channel_name,offset_date=seven_days, limit=100)    
        msglist = [msg.__dict__ for msg in hist_iter]
        df = pd.DataFrame(msglist)
        print(df.head(5))
 
    return f'it works!:{request_json}'
```

**The error message I get from GCF log:**

> File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in
> get_event_loop raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in
> thread %r.' RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread
> 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.

## Update

I updated the code, the runtime error gone. but I am getting time out error.
I put the timeout 180 secondes, but still when I test the function times out on 60 seconds.

**Here is the updated code. Is there something I am doing wrong?**

```
async def foo():
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from pandas import DataFrame
    from pyrogram import Client
    import asyncio

    session_string = "********zNmkubA4ibjsdjhsdfjlhweruifnjkldfioY5DE*********"    
    api_id = 325511548224831351
    api_hash = "jdffjgtrkjhfklmrtgjtrm;sesews;;wex"        
    channel_name = 'cnn'

    with Client(session_string, api_id, api_hash, takeout=True) as app:
        hist_iter = app.iter_history(
            channel_name, limit=10)
        msglist = [msg.__dict__ for msg in hist_iter]
        df = DataFrame(msglist)    
    return df
 
async def bar():
    return await foo() 

def test(request):
    from asyncio import run
    return run(bar())
```

Comment: See this for possible answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601056/can-i-use-python-aiohttp-inside-of-a-gcp-cloud-function

Comment: Thank you @Kolban it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in the end was to change from Pyrogram to telethon and create the asyncio manaually before creating the client.

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

**Note:** you need valid session string, otherwise when you test the function, it will wait for you to auth with mobile number. so first run this code locally and authenticate, then copy the session string to the cloud function.

Here is the full code:

```
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon import TelegramClient
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

api_id = 101010101
api_hash = "jhafcgahagfbahgdbw17171736456gerf"
session_string = "hjksdhjbdsfhgbdsabeyitrgdsbfsdbdiyfhsbddasbdjdksf="
channel_name = 'bbcuzbek'
seven_days = int((datetime.datetime.now() -
                  datetime.timedelta(days=7)).timestamp())




client = TelegramClient(StringSession(session_string),
                        api_id, api_hash, loop=loop)

time_format = "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"
download_date = datetime.datetime.now(
    tz=datetime.timezone.utc).strftime(time_format)

cols = ["id", "date", "text", "views", "download_date"]


async def foo():
    all_msgs = [[message.id, message.date.strftime(time_format), message.text, message.views, download_date] async for message in client.iter_messages(entity=channel_name, offset_date=seven_days, limit=10)]
    df = DataFrame(data=all_msgs, columns=cols)
    # write it to BQ
    # print(df)
    # async for message in client.iter_messages(entity=channel_name, offset_date=seven_days, limit=10):
    #     print(message.id, message.date, message.text, message.views)
    print("it runs")

    print(len(df))
    return None


def test(request):
    with client:
        return client.loop.run_until_complete(foo())
```

Comment: @Mo-Huss.Hi. I know this is over a year old, but I'd really like to see your code snippet (above) in the context of your other code. I want to do something similar, I just don't know where your snippet here belongs in the cloud function. Was it added to the test() function?

Comment: @kfranz sorry for late reply, I have added the full code above.

Answer (score 2):

1. `bar()` is redundant
2. You're trying to return a dataframe. Is it a valid HTTP response?
3. `with` -> `async with`
4. `hist_iter = app.iter_history()` -> `hist_iter = await app.iter_history()`
5. M.b. it waits for input?
   [image]

Comment: Thanks @madbird, I tried your suggestion and get the same runtime error before.

Comment: It did not work. I ended changing from Pyrogram to telethon. and then creating new asyncio loop and using it instead of the defualt one.

Comment: Do gcp cloud function supports asyncio feature in python?