# Python asyncio with cloud function and global async initialization

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, functions-framework

I have come across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755996/can-or-how-to-use-python-asyncio-on-google-cloud-functions) to use asyncio with google cloud functions

However, I would also like to do some async initialization

```
asyncio.run(some_async_global_init())

@functions_framework.http
def cloudFunction(request: Request):
    asyncio.run(async_task())
```

However I get `Event loop is closed` when i do that

I have tried opening a new event loop instead of asyncio.run. But I got `Task attached to a different loop` error. It would look like this

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(async_global_init())


@functions_framework.http
def cloudFunction(request: Request):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(async_task())
```

A workaround is to do the initialization as part of the task, but ideally I would like to take advantage of this global initialization tip as stated in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations)

Comment: This might stackoverflow answer might help you:

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600858/19229284](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600858/19229284)