# There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-2_1'."

Tags: google-cloud-functions, python-asyncio, functions-framework

I am deploying a cloud function to GCP using functions_framework.

I have an asynchronous function that I call with asyncio.run, and I get this error. Can anyone explain why i encounter this and how to solve it ? My setup looks like this

```
async def task():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def on_event(cloud_event: CloudEvent):
    asyncio.run(task())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can or How to use Python asyncio on Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755996/can-or-how-to-use-python-asyncio-on-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: No, I'm doing exactly as the answer of that question